# Jenkins scheduled backup pipeline - Make sure all jobs are stopped before run

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a Jenkins pipeline that runs overnight to do the backup.
I need to find a way to only run the pipeline when all the other jobs are done and make sure that no other job gets triggered meanwhile.
That should be similar to what this plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/exclusive-execution/ is doing.
But "exclusive execution" is not supported for declarative pipelines.

I'm attaching my Jenkinsfile just in case someone needs to take a look:

```
def BACKUP_DATETIME = new Date().format('yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss', TimeZone.getTimeZone('Canada/Eastern'))

pipeline {
    agent { label 'master' }
    options {
        //Build options
        disableResume()
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
        buildDiscarder(
          logRotator (
                       artifactDaysToKeepStr: '10',
                       artifactNumToKeepStr: '1',
                       daysToKeepStr: '30',
                       numToKeepStr: '30'
                     )
        )
    }
    triggers { cron('TZ=Canada/Eastern\n0 3 * * *') }
    environment {
        GIT_SSH_KEY_ID = 'gitlab_builduser'
        BACKUP_PREFIX_NAME = 'jenkins-back-'
        BACKUP_REPO_NAME = "jenkins_backups"
        BACKUP_REPO_URL = "git@XXX:XX/${env.BACKUP_REPO_NAME}.git"
        NUMBER_OF_BACKUPS = '7'
        GOOGLE_CHAT_TOKEN = 'XXXXXF'
        JENKINS_VERSION = ''
    }
    stages {
        stage('Init') {
            steps {
                script {
                    env.JENKINS_VERSION = sh(script: "java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --version", returnStdout: true).trim()
                }
                dir("/tmp") {
                  withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: "${env.GIT_SSH_KEY_ID}", keyFileVariable: 'SSH_KEY', usernameVariable: 'SSH_USER')]) {
                    withEnv(["GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -i ${SSH_KEY}"]) {
                        sh '''
                          if [ ! -d ${BACKUP_REPO_NAME} ]
                          then
                            git clone ${BACKUP_REPO_URL}
                          else
                            cd ${BACKUP_REPO_NAME}
                            git fetch origin
                            git reset --hard origin/master
                          fi
                        '''
                    }
                  }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Backup') {
            steps {
                dir ('jenkins_backup') {
                  sh """
                    chmod +x ./jenkins-backup.sh
                    ./jenkins-backup.sh ${JENKINS_HOME} /tmp/${env.BACKUP_REPO_NAME}/${BACKUP_PREFIX_NAME}_${BACKUP_DATETIME}.tar.gz
                  """
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Upload') {
            steps {
                // TO_DO: SAVE THE BACKUP file
                dir("/tmp/${env.BACKUP_REPO_NAME}") {
                  withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: "${env.GIT_SSH_KEY_ID}", keyFileVariable: 'SSH_KEY', usernameVariable: 'SSH_USER')]) {
                    withEnv(["GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -i ${SSH_KEY}"]) {
                        sh '''
                          git config user.email "${SSH_USER}@email.com"
                          git config user.name "${SSH_USER}"
                          # backup only keep the lastest X backup-files
                          ls -tp ${BACKUP_PREFIX_NAME}_*.tar.gz | grep -v '/$' | tail -n +$(expr ${NUMBER_OF_BACKUPS} + 1) | xargs -I {} rm -- {}
                          # Push to git
                          git add --all
                          git status
                          git commit --amend -CHEAD --allow-empty
                          git push --force-with-lease origin master
                          env
                        '''
                    }
                  }
                }

            }
        }
    }
    post {
        failure {
          hangoutsNotify message: "${JOB_BASE_NAME} faild!",token: "${env.GOOGLE_CHAT_TOKEN}",threadByJob: true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what you asked for, but why not use an existing plugin like [Thin backup](https://github.com/jenkinsci/thin-backup-plugin) that will do the backup for you with all the requirements you specified above out of the box.   
Combined with the [Filesystem Trigger Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/fstrigger/) you can then achieve exactly what you want - it will notify you when a backup is created an allow you to handle the back file however you want.

Comment: that's a good approach but requires manual steps, in my case Ièm looking for a way to set that programmatically so I can replicate the steps on multiple instances with no effort, I want to control the way we do the backup via a script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a groovy script that will do what I need. The script will list all currently running and queued jobs except the backup job and put a timer if one of the lists is not empty. When all the jobs are in an idle state the backup will continue running.

I will attach my scripts here:

Jenkinsfile:

```
def BACKUP_DATETIME = new Date().format('yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss', TimeZone.getTimeZone('Canada/Eastern'))

pipeline {
    agent { label 'master' }
    options {
        //Build options
        disableResume()
        disableConcurrentBuilds()
        buildDiscarder(
          logRotator (
                       artifactDaysToKeepStr: '10',
                       artifactNumToKeepStr: '1',
                       daysToKeepStr: '30',
                       numToKeepStr: '30'
                     )
        )
    }
    triggers { cron('TZ=Canada/Eastern\n0 3 * * *') }
    environment {
        GIT_SSH_KEY_ID = 'gitlab_builduser'
        BACKUP_PREFIX_NAME = 'jenkins-backup'
        BACKUP_REPO_NAME = "jenkins_backups"
        BACKUP_REPO_URL = "git@XXXX/${env.BACKUP_REPO_NAME}.git"
        NUMBER_OF_BACKUPS = '7'
        GOOGLE_CHAT_TOKEN = 'XXXX'
        JENKINS_VERSION = ''
    }
    stages {
        stage('Init') {
            steps {
                script {
                    env.JENKINS_VERSION = sh(script: "java -jar /usr/share/jenkins/jenkins.war --version", returnStdout: true).trim()
                    def safeBackupModule = load("${WORKSPACE}/jenkins_backup/safe_backup_run.groovy")
                    safeBackupModule.jenkins_safe_backup("${env.JOB_NAME}")

                }
                dir("/tmp") {
                  withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: "${env.GIT_SSH_KEY_ID}", keyFileVariable: 'SSH_KEY', usernameVariable: 'SSH_USER')]) {
                    withEnv(["GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -i ${SSH_KEY}"]) {
                        sh '''
                          if [ ! -d ${BACKUP_REPO_NAME} ]
                          then
                            git clone ${BACKUP_REPO_URL}
                          else
                            cd ${BACKUP_REPO_NAME}
                            git fetch origin
                            git reset --hard origin/master
                          fi
                        '''
                    }
                  }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Backup') {
            steps {
                dir ('jenkins_backup') {
                  sh """
                    chmod +x ./jenkins-backup.sh
                    ./jenkins-backup.sh ${JENKINS_HOME} /tmp/${env.BACKUP_REPO_NAME}/${BACKUP_PREFIX_NAME}_${BACKUP_DATETIME}.tar.gz
                  """
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Upload') {
            steps {
                // TO_DO: SAVE THE BACKUP file
                dir("/tmp/${env.BACKUP_REPO_NAME}") {
                  withCredentials([sshUserPrivateKey(credentialsId: "${env.GIT_SSH_KEY_ID}", keyFileVariable: 'SSH_KEY', usernameVariable: 'SSH_USER')]) {
                    withEnv(["GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -i ${SSH_KEY}"]) {
                        sh '''
                          git config user.email "${SSH_USER}@XXX.com"
                          git config user.name "${SSH_USER}"
                          # backup only keep the lastest X backup-files
                          ls -tp ${BACKUP_PREFIX_NAME}_*.tar.gz | grep -v '/$' | tail -n +$(expr ${NUMBER_OF_BACKUPS} + 1) | xargs -I {} rm -- {}
                          # Push to git
                          git add --all
                          git status
                          git commit --amend -CHEAD --allow-empty
                          git push --force-with-lease origin master
                          env
                        '''
                    }
                  }
                }

            }
        }
    }
    post {
        failure {
          hangoutsNotify message: "${JOB_BASE_NAME} faild!",token: "${env.GOOGLE_CHAT_TOKEN}",threadByJob: true
        }
    }
}
```

Groovy script "safe_backup_run.groovy":

```
import hudson.model.RestartListener
import jenkins.model.*;

//backup method
def jenkins_safe_backup(job_name) {
    //set the
    if(!binding.hasVariable('timeout_seconds')) {
        timeout_seconds = 60
    }

    if(timeout_seconds in String) {
        timeout_seconds = Integer.decode(timeout_seconds)
    }

    //type check user defined parameters/bindings
    if(!(timeout_seconds in Integer)) {
        throw new Exception('PARAMETER ERROR: timeout_seconds must be an integer.')
    }
    print("Jenkins safe backup initiated.")
    while(true) {
        //get the list of all the currenty running jobs
        runningBuilds = Jenkins.instance.getView('All').getBuilds().findAll() { it.getResult().equals(null) }
        //remove the 'Jenkins_Backup' job from the list
        runningBuilds.removeAll { it.toString().toLowerCase().startsWith(job_name.toLowerCase()) }
        //get the list of queued jobs
        def queuedBuilds = []
        Jenkins.instance.queue.items.findAll { queuedBuilds.add(it.task.name) }
        //remove the 'Jenkins_Backup' job from the list
        queuedBuilds.removeAll { it.toString().toLowerCase().startsWith(job_name.toLowerCase()) }

        //If no job is running except 'Jenkins_Backup' break
        if((runningBuilds.isEmpty()) && (queuedBuilds.isEmpty())) {
            break
        }
        print("Jenkins jobs/queue are not idle.  Waiting ${timeout_seconds} seconds before next backup attempt.")
        print("RUNNING jobs: " + runningBuilds)
        print("QUEUED jobs: " + queuedBuilds)
        sleep(timeout_seconds)
    }
}

return this
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to achive this if you are running these jobs on one node. Use BuildBLocker plugin.

Install it from here:
https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-blocker-plugin/

The sample usage can look as follows:

```
pipelineJob('MyPipeline') {

    // Block build if certain jobs are running.
    blockOn('.*AnotherPipeline.*') {
        // Possible values are 'GLOBAL' and 'NODE' (default).
        blockLevel('GLOBAL')
        // Possible values are 'ALL', 'BUILDABLE' and 'DISABLED' (default).
        scanQueueFor('DISABLED')
}
```

}

You can also do this directly from GUI:
[image]

and set the additional options:
[image]

Hope it helps. Regards!

Comment: It could have been the perfect solution but the plugin is not supported for declarative pipelines  I have tried adding that "blockOn" block everywhere but Jenkins does like that!.
I ended up writing my own groovy script that will get invoked b the pipeline to wait till the other jobs are done before triggering the backup. Attached bellow my solution (still not perfect)

Comment: looks nice. What about thrrotle option>? Maybe there is a way to allow only one build to run at the same time..